# How to load entire Solr index into memory to increase performance?

Tags: caching, indexing, solr, lucene, solr4

My website gets 10 - 30 hits per second (including bot crawls). I indexed 6 millions records (from a mysql table) in Solr. When I retrieve 30 records using `q=something` and `sort=random_`, Solr takes 200 to 300 milliseconds to respond, sometimes 100ms.

I tried to improve retrieval using `solr.RAMDirectoryFactory` setting but I got an out of memory error. I know `solr.RAMDirectoryFactory` setting is not persistent. So, which is best option to increase caching and loading whole index into memory.

I am using Digital Ocean 8GB server for Solr.

Solr Settings..

```
 <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>

 <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                     size="512"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="0"/>

<documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>
```

Solr version:

```
solr-spec 7.2.1
solr-impl 7.2.1 b2b6438b37073bee1fca40374e85bf91aa457c0b - ubuntu - 2018-01-10 00:54:21
lucene-spec 7.2.1
lucene-impl 7.2.1 b2b6438b37073bee1fca40374e85bf91aa457c0b - ubuntu - 2018-01
```

Arguments:

```
-DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks-DSTOP.PORT=7983-Djetty.home=/opt/solr/server-Djetty.port=8983-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/var/solr/log4j.properties-Dsolr.data.home=-Dsolr.default.confdir=/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf-Dsolr.install.dir=/opt/solr-Dsolr.jetty.https.port=8983-Dsolr.log.dir=/var/solr/logs-Dsolr.log.muteconsole-Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/data-Duser.timezone=UTC-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps-XX:+PrintGCDetails-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation-XX:+UseParNewGC-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50-XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000-XX:ConcGCThreads=4-XX:GCLogFileSize=20M-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8-XX:NewRatio=3-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=9-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/opt/solr/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 /var/solr/logs-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m-XX:SurvivorRatio=4-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90-Xloggc:/var/solr/logs/solr_gc.log-Xms512m-Xmx512m-Xss256k-verbose:gc
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the index can't be kept in RAM (.. from your out of memory message), how do you expect that to work?

Comment: i increased memory from Xms512m-Xmx512m to  Xms3g-Xmx3g now. iam looking for better cache options instead of solr.RAMDirectoryFactory  setting

Comment: Start by looking at cache utilization under the Solr admin page - if the hit rate is very low, you might have to increase the cache sizes. The format of your queries and your filters will also affect how the cache is utilized.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that with an 8GB server and Solr Heap set to 512M that Lucene (not Solr!) will use the rest of the available memory on the machine (minus what the O.S. needs etc.)

So let's say for example that the OS needs 512M of RAM, and your Solr Heap is 512M - then there's 7GB left for Lucene. If you are new to Solr and Lucene [this](https://dzone.com/articles/use-lucene%E2%80%99s-mmapdirectory) is a great read on how Lucene's memory works.

How big are your indexes? You can check your `/solr/data` folders with `du -h`.

To clarify ***INCREASING*** Solr Heap will make the situation worse (there will be less memory for Lucene). To avoid swapping of RAM to disk you also need to turn off swap (see for example [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/684771/best-way-to-disable-swap-in-linux)).

There are lots of knobs and buttons in Solr and Lucene and your instance that need to be tweaked to help ensure your entire index is in memory. Even then remember that things like Java GC, CPU speed, memory speed, and having the index pre-warmed into memory will impact response time significantly.

To learn more see

- http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/04/catching-slowdowns-in-lucene.html
- https://lucidworks.com/2011/09/14/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/
- https://vienergie.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/solr-tuning-maximizing-your-solr-performance/
- http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/11/lucene-with-zing-part-2.html

Comment: Wouldn't Solr and Lucene run under the same JVM constraints, and thus, the memory allocated would be from the same pool, regardless of which part of the library was running? If you're talking about memory mapped files instead, that's handled on the OS level and is not Lucene specific (you can also preload the index files into the OS file level cache in that case if necessary).

Comment: Yes but when most people think about "keeping the index in memory" - it's off heap memory.

Comment: I don't think, turning off the swap is an good idea: there are some parts of data at the memory, which are rarely in use, like some specific OS cache or other, sleeping daemons. For unneeded processes, the swap is the right place. If there is no swap available, all those unused, sleeping processes will block RAM space instead of swap space.

Comment: It's counter-intuitive but please read http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/04/just-say-no-to-swapping.html